# Hide popup after button press. React Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a some popup block or modal window as you like. And I want that it will close after I press on button. Button will be visible after checkboox will be true. Help me pls. May be I have to add something to css, or JS code is incorrect. 
Code is below.

```js
class ModalWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      checked: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    })
  }


  hide() {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  }

  show() {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
    });


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.show();
  }



  render() {
    const buttonContent = this.state.checked ?  <div className={s.showButton}>
      <button onClick={() => this.hide()} className={s.closeBtn}>Confirm yes yes</button>
    </div> : null;
    
    return (
      <div className={this.state.open ? 'show':'hide'}>
        <div className={s.modal}>

          <h2 className={s.modalText}>Some text in block</h2>
          <label>I want to confirm</label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          {buttonContent}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(ModalWindow);
```

```css
.modal {
  background:#fff;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #0000ee;

}

.hide {
display:none
}

.modalText {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
}

label {
  margin:0 15px 0 0;
}

.closeBtn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0 0 0 100px;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  border: none;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Looks like the code is there to hide it, it's hard to determine exactly what is wrong without a runnable demo or more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With react you have another way to do hiding and showing of elements. You just render it or you don't. 
So instead of setting the state inside the modal dialog to show or hide the modal dialog you should have a property outside of it which decides if this dialog is rendered. Your React App should look something like this:

```
class ComponentWithModalDialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {showModal} = this.props;


    if(showModal) {
      return <ModalWindow />
    }
    else {
      return <div>
        other content
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```